# CapturedImage in ARFrame to portrait/vertical

Tags: ios, arkit

The CapturedImage in ARFrame is landscape/horizontal. How can I change it to Portrait?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There's an API for that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhkxDIr0y2U)

`ARFrame.`[`displayTransform(for:viewportSize:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransform) gives you a transform matrix that rotates from the image's sensor-native orientation to whatever UI orientation you specify, and provides a scale factor to fit a viewport whose aspect ratio doesn't necessarily match that of the camera.

You can then use that transform in whatever display pipeline you're working with to show the rotated image. For example:

- check the Xcode project template for a Metal-based ARKit app to see how they feed that transform matrix to a vertex shader.
- create a Core Image `CIImage` from the pixel buffer, then use [`transformed(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1438203-transformed) to get a rotated image, which you can then convert to `UIImage` and display in `UIImageView`.

Comment: displayTransform doesn't just rotate, but also shifts and scales to aspect fill. Unless you are doing low-level drawing, this is probably not what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903747/wrong-image-orientation-after-displaytransform-call/67083525#67083525

Comment: I always get the same strange result regardless of the device's orientation: `CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d:-1.0, tx: 1.0, ty:1.0)`

Answer (score 0):

`frame.displayTransform(for: .portrait, viewportSize: CGSize(width: height, height: width)).inverted()` rotated my portrait `CGRect` to the landscape orientation that `ARFrame` captures images with.