# Wrong image orientation after displayTransform call

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, ciimage, cvpixelbuffer

I am trying to get the image from the current `ARFrame` by using:

```
if let imageBuffer = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage {
    let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    let viewportSize = sceneView.bounds.size
    let transformation = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.displayTransform(for: orientation, viewportSize: viewportSize)

    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer).transformed(by: transformation)
}
```

For landscape, it works great. For portrait, I get the image at a wrong angle (rotated by 180). Any idea why?

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cG5P.png)

[image: output]

[Expected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aflGN.png)

[image: expected]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimageoption/2915369-applyorientationproperty

Comment: @SachinVas Tried it, doesn't work... As far as I know, this uses the metadata from the image

Answer (score 2):

> **At first I should say that it definitely is an unpleasant bug**.

A problem is, when you convert an `Portrait` image, what ARFrame contains, to CIImage or CGImage, it loses its orientation and rotates it 180 degrees CCW. This issue affects only `Portrait` images. `Landscape` ones are not affected at all.

This happens because `Portrait` image doesn't have an info about its orientation at conversion stage, and thus, an image in portrait remains in portrait mode even though it's converted to CIImage or CGImage.

To fix this you should compare **"standard" landscape's** `width`/`height` with a **"non-standard" portrait's** `width`/`height`, and if these values are different, rotate an image to **180 degrees CW** (or apply orientation case [.portraitUpsideDown](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation/portraitupsidedown)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn’t this what `displayTransform` is supposed to do?

Comment: Any idea why? If I pass `.portraitUpsideDown` instead of `.portrait` (and viceversa) it works as expected...

Comment: `.portraitUpsideDown` is the same as `rotate 180 degrees CW`. ))))

Comment: I have just seen your edit, thank you for explaining

Comment: @Andy displayTransform also scales and shifts coordinates around, which is probably not what you want to do. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Coordinate systems**

We need to be very clear about which coordinate system we are working in.
We know UIKit has `(0,0)` in the top left, and `(1,1)` in the top right, but this is not true of CoreImage:

> Due to Core Image's coordinate system mismatch with UIKit... (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437833-cropped))

or Vision (including CoreML recognition):

> Vision uses a normalized coordinate space from 0.0 to 1.0 with lower
> left origin. (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision))

However, `displayTransform` uses the UIKit orientation:

> A transform matrix that converts from normalized image coordinates in
> the captured image to normalized image coordinates that account for
> the specified parameters. Normalized image coordinates range from
> (0,0) in the upper left corner of the image to (1,1) in the lower
> right corner. (See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransform))

So, if you load a `CVPixelBuffer` into a `CIImage`, and then try to apply
the `displayTransform` matrix, it's going to be flipped (as you can see).
But, also it messes up the image.

**What display transform does**

Display transform appears to be mainly for Metal, or other lower level drawing routines which tend to match the core image orientation.
The transformation scales the image and shifts it so it "aspect fills" within the specified bounds.

If you are going to display the image in a `UIImageView` then it will be reversed because their orientations differ. But furthermore, the image view does the aspect fill transformation for you,
so there is no reason to shift or scale, and thus no reason to use `displayTransform` at all. Just rotate the image to the proper orientation.

```
// apply an orientation. You can easily make a function
// which converts the screen orientation to this parameter

let rotated = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage).oriented(...)
imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: rotated)
```

If you want to overlay content on the image, such as by adding subviews to the `UIImageView`, then `displayTransform` can be helpful.
It will translate image coordinates (in UIKit orientation), into coordinates in the image view
which line up with the displayed image (which is shifted and scaled due to aspect fill).